# Trouble re-authenticating Google sign-in after signing for the second time. (Swift 3)(Firebase)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin

Question: How do I get the google sign-in page every time user signs-in after signing out?

Issue: Once user signs in for the first time (google sign in pops up) and once the user signs in for the second time. (the google sign in page doesn't pop up) and signs in the user w/o signing in again with their user Google credentials (eg. email, password)

**Google Sign-out Button Function**

```
// Sign user out of main application
@IBAction func signOutButtonDidTouch(_ sender: Any) {

    // Firebase user authentication fuction
    let firebaseAuth = FIRAuth.auth()

    if firebaseAuth?.currentUser != nil {

    // If there is a user signed-in
    do {
        try firebaseAuth?.signOut()

        print("[Google] signing out successful")

            if firebaseAuth?.currentUser == nil {
                // Performs current view controller transition to SignInViewController
                performSegue(withIdentifier: "signOutSegue", sender: self)
            }
        }catch let signOutError as NSError {

        print("Error signing out: %@", signOutError)
        print("[Google] signing out error")
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using firebase-ui?

Comment: Yes, GIDSignInUIDelegate

Comment: Can you paste in the code you use to log a user out with?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: Ian beat me to it

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses Chris!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You sign out of Firebase Auth, but you're still signed in with Google (there is a token in the keychain on the device). If you sign out of the Google account as well, that should address it:

```
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signOut()
```

Firebase Auth treats Google as just another identity provider, as with Facebook or Twitter, so it doesn't tweak the state of that when the Firebase Auth state changes.

Comment: What is GIDSignIn?

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem. Firstly I can login with email and password. 
Then I can signing with google successfully. 
After that, I tried to logout from Google again. 
When I re-authenticaite with email and password, this message is returned: "The password is invalid or the user does not have a password." 
On Firebase console, the users account symbol change from mail to Google. 
I couldn't solve this problem. What is my wrong?

In AppDelegate.swift:

```
func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {

    if let error = error {
        log.debug("Error Google Sign-in: \(error)")
        return
    }

    guard let authentication = user.authentication else { return }
    let credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(withIDToken: authentication.idToken,
                                                   accessToken: authentication.accessToken)

    Auth.auth().signInAndRetrieveData(with: credential) { (authResult, error) in

        if let error = error {
            log.error(error)
            return
        }
        // User is signed in
    }
}
```

This is the logout button action:

```
@IBAction func logout_TouchUpInside(_ sender: Any) {

    do {
        try Auth.auth().signOut()
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signOut()

    } catch let error {
        self.writeReport(string: error.localizedDescription)
        log.error(error.localizedDescription)
        self.showAlert(title: "Error", message: error.localizedDescription)

    }
    log.info("After  logout current user: \(String(describing: Auth.auth().currentUser))")
}
```